# Microsoft Graph get filename

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

Currently stuck with getting the filename of a ressource from SharePoint online aka Office 365. Authentication and refresh token is from the Unified Api example aka Microsoft Graph.

```
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(   
...
var imgBytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(parameters.FileGet);
return File(imgBytes, "application/specialFormat", "File1.specialFormat");
```

At the moment I have to define my own filename. I' ve already seen the example at http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/overview, but the "GET my files" example shows only how to get the files of one person and not how to get a filename based upon a file Id. I hope someone could clarify this.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
```

Is getting a filename based upon the file id with the Graph api possible or do I have to use something else?

EDIT 
Some queries that would work:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$select=id
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$filter=name eq 'testfile.office'
```

But if I try to search for the specific id the query fails and I get none information.

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$filter=id eq '01QXOQU7OCV7FW2BQNAZD3KNZMYXVMNJD6'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the item ID, you can access the item like this:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/ID`

If you have the path, you can access the item like this:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/FOLDER/FOLDER/FOLDER/FILENAME.EXT`

You can further get the children of an item by path:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/FOLDER/FOLDER/FOLDER/FILENAME.EXT:/children`

The Drive API exposed through MS Graph is pretty much (if not exactly) the same as the API exposed by OneDrive. See this reference page:
https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/item.htm